# .NET JsonExtensionData analogy for Xml deserialization

Tags: .net, xml, serialization, xml-deserialization

In Newtonsoft Json deserializer there is an attribute [JsonExtensionDataAttribute](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonExtensionDataAttribute.htm), which allows to deserialize to dictionary all JTokens that class didn't have matching members for.

Is there anything similar for Xml serialization in .NET?

E.g.: I have XML:

```
<MyCustomObject>
   <classProp1>Value 1</classProp1>
   <dynamicProp1>dynamic prop value</dynamicProp1>
   <dynamicProp2>dynamic prop 2 value<dynamicProp2>
<MyCustomObject>
```

Which I'd like to map to the class:

```
public class MyCustomObject
{
   public string classProp1 {get;set;}

   [XmlExtensionData]
   public IDictionary<string, XNode> AdditionalData{get;set;}
}
```

so all unmatched Xml nodes (dynamicProp1, dynamicProp2) will go to AdditionalData dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

I found the easiest solution using already existing attributes:

> [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlanyelementattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)
>
> [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlanyattributeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Example:

```
public class MyCustomObject
{
   public string classProp1 {get;set;}

   [XmlAnyElement]
   public XmlElement[] AdditionalElements {get;set;}

   [XmlAnyAttribute]
   public XmlAttribute[] AdditionalAttrs {get;set;}
}
```

This works both for Serialization and Deserialization.
During deserialization all unmatched nodes will be pushed to the AdditionalElements array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `UnknownElement` event.

```cs
var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyCustomObject));
xs.UnknownElement += Xs_UnknownElement;

MyCustomObject my;
using (var fs = new FileStream("test.xml", FileMode.Open))
    my = (MyCustomObject)xs.Deserialize(fs);
```

```cs
void Xs_UnknownElement(object sender, XmlElementEventArgs e)
{
    var my = (MyCustomObject)e.ObjectBeingDeserialized;
    if (my.AdditionalData == null)
        my.AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    my.AdditionalData[e.Element.LocalName] = e.Element.InnerText;
}
```

```cs
public class MyCustomObject
{
    public string classProp1 { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public IDictionary<string, string> AdditionalData { get; set; }
}
```

Note the `XmlIgnore` attribute. We must use it in order to trigger the event.